# Reduce requests number on counters maintainment

Tags: javascript, ios, parse-platform

Let's say I have a Parse model `Book` which has a property `pagesViewCount`, and a Parse model `Page` which has properties `book`, and `viewCount`.

As Parse doesn't support aggregation(SUM), when my client sees a page I have to increment both values to keep them sync.

For now, I call a cloud function `markAsRead` which receives a pageObjectId as param, and from there, fetches the page, and call:

```
page.increment('viewCount');
page.get("book").increment("pagesViewCount")
Parse.Object.saveAll([page, page.get("book")])
```

This works well, except that this involves multiplying requests, and as Parse only allows a burst limit of 30req/sec, I guess this could be a big problem without having so much users.

Is there any alternative to this ?

PS : I think I could just call `page.save()` instead of savingAll page & book because of recursivity, but that'll be the same number of request for less readability, right ?

Edit: `Page` and `Book` objects are only examples, my objects are more complex and subobject is not finite, so I can't store their viewCount along with main object within an array

Answer (score 0):

To reduce the number of requests, you can store the counters locally and then call a function every time your app closes. This function aggregates the counters for all pages.

I would also consider if you can rethink your data model to maybe not store a full object for every page in a book? How is `Book`, `Page` and the current user related?

One possible solution could be to have a field in `Book` (if this is specific to the current user) called `pagesRead`, and this could be an array. Every time the user reads a page, you add the page number to this array. Number of pages read is then equal to the size of this array. Whether a page is read or not is just a matter of

```
pagesRead.contains(pageNo)
```

Depending on your needs and use case, there could be other similar solutions that maybe do not include a `Page` object.

Comment: `Page` and `Book` objects are only examples for that use case. In my real case, storing individual values of read in an array isn't really a good option because subobjects don't have a finite number, thus could increase too much the size of the container object. But the first part of your answer is interesting

Comment: I understand. The book case would usually include a couple of hundred items and rarely more than 1000. Which would not be a problem. If there can be thousands and thousands of objects, then that is probably not the right solution. But you will still struggle if you need to update hundreds of pages across all your users. I still believe there could be data model solutions to this, depending on your use case.

Comment: That said; a user will spend some time on each page, so you need a decent number of users to have to update more than 30 pages every second. By that time, maybe your app is popular enough that you can afford a paid plan? Or redesign your data model? I would probably try redesigning your data model now, but be careful not to prematurely optimise your app for volumes you are unlikely to get in a long time.

Comment: In my case, a page is a media, and a book, a group. Users can post media to groups, and there are counters for total of media seen by groups, and total of views for a media. Indeed this is not a problem for the moment, but I can't think of any way to bypass this by the time it will be a problem

Comment: Redesign the data model could be ok for the moment, but I don't think there is a better way to represent such a relation

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately currently each operation in a batch operation is counted as a single API request ([source](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/parse-developers/ssvkFis62YE)), this means that if you want to save 30 objects simultaneously, you might hit the free plan limits. You need to bear in mind that requests/second limit is calculated on a per-minute basis. From [Parse FAQ](https://parse.com/plans/faq):

> The request limit is calculated on a per-minute basis for each app.
>   For example, if an app is set to 30 requests/second, your app will hit
>   its request limit once that specific app sends more than 1800 requests
>   over a 60 second period

The solution to avoid the requests/second limit is to spread your operations over multiple API requests. For example, use Promise chaining in your Cloud Code to perform your save/update operations in multiple steps over a longer period of time to make sure you do not hit the free plan ceiling.

Comment: Already aware of that and doing so, but in the case that I'm describing, that's not really relevant